# ¿Cómo soluciono en Excel un error de formulas que al editar un vinculo se convierte en #valor?

Tags: excel

La fórmula es la siguiente:
=CONTAR.SI.CONJUNTO([00.ARCHIVO.xlsm]resultados_GDS!$N:$N;B4;[00.ARCHIVO.xlsm]resultados_GDS!$M:$M;A5;[00.ARCHIVO.xlsm]resultados_GDS!$B:$B;"WQUA*")
Cuando abro el archivo que contiene la fórmula en la casilla aparece #VALOR. Si no actualizo los vinculos me aparecen los datos correctos:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Sin embargo en cuanto los actualizo ya directamente me aparece el error.

Me pasa muy a menudo, lo he probado con nuevos informes para intentar solventarlo y no hay manera siempre aparece este fallo...
?alguien tan amable me puede decir que me pasa?

Mil gracias de antenmano
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Hola Cristina, por lo que comentas parece que al actualizar los "links" estos rompen el acceso a los datos, es decir, parece ser como que los enlaces antiguos "apuntan correctamente" a unos datos. Al actualizar, dejan de apuntar y, digamos que faltan datos o falta algo de la fóruma por lo que falla y no calcula correctamente. Te sugiero hacer pruebas del estilo a comparar la fóruma "actualizando y sin actualizar", seguramente podrás ver "a donde apunta", es decir a donde enlaza y donde en realidad están tus datos. ¿Quizás tengas que actualizarlos/moverlos de excel?

Answer (score 1):

Solo añadir que, aunque Excel admite el uso en formulas de vínculos a archivos externos, puede haber problemas a la hora de actualizar los datos vinculados. Por lo que comentas, y por lo que dice microsoft [aquí](https://support.microsoft.com/es-es/help/925893/external-links-may-be-calculated-when-you-open-a-workbook-that-was-las) el problema puede venir que si los archivos vinculados no están disponibles al abrir, y excel devuelve un error (o por otros motivos).
Y lo peor es que si guardas los cambios al salir, se quedarán los errores. ¿por qué? te preguntarás. Pues porque excel al hacer referencias a archivos externos crea una tabla interna con los datos del otro libro...y si guardas el fichero se quedan los errores. Por eso cuando abres te funcionan los vínculos (usa una tabla anterior) y al dar actualizar te falla.

Lee el artículo del link, ahí te explica como saber por qué pueden fallan los vínculos.

Como consejo, lo mejor es obtener esos datos vinculándolos como datos externos bajo Microsoft Query.

Pasos:
Pentaña Datos - De otras Fuentes - Desde Microsoft Query - Excel Files - Buscar la ruta del fichero - Y te pedirá que indiques en qué hoja de tu libro quieres ver los datos (generalmente fila1, columna1)

Nota importante: Los datos tienen que estar normalizados. Primera fila del fichero excel tiene que contener los nombres de campo. Si no es así...normalízalos antes.

La ventaja es que ese tipo de conexiones son más estables y lo mejor es que los datos vinculados estarán visibles en tu excel (verás la tabla vinculada), además de otras ventajas. Pero no te voy a liar más. Si te decides a usar Query...pregunta

Answer (score 0):

Muchísimas gracias por tomaros la molestia en contestar.
[image]

Cada vez que intento actualizar vínculos ( el archivo origen nunca cambia la ubicación) se me queda el excel pensando y me da error.... No se porqué sucede esto.
He seguido paso por paso el link que me envías para que reconozca los orígenes y sigue dándome el mismo fallo..

Al rato de quedarse medio enganchado me da el vinculo ok:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y me vuelve a desconfigurar la fórmula.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Es curioso que esto no pase si la vinculación la hago a una celda y no hay fórmulas de por medio... no se como resolverlo :( millones de gracias

Answer (score 0):

Visto que no te convence el uso de Query...
Lo único que se me ocurre es que crees un nuevo libro, con distinto nombre.
No sé por qué me da que el nombre [00.ARCHIVO.xlsm] al llevar doble punto...o por otro motivo..no enlaza. Además creándolo de nuevo se debería solucionar.

No se la destreza que tienes con Excel pero la idea es crear un nuevo libro [00.ARCHIVO.xlsm] con un nuevo nombre. Si es complejo y todos los datos/hojas no pueden ser nuevos, la idea es que la Hoja vinculada (hacia donde apuntan las fórmulas) sea nueva, osea creada desde cero, copiar desde el original y pegar en la copia. Dejando los mismos nombres de hoja/original - que - hoja/copia , así como los datos iguales

Una vez tengas dicho nuevo libro partiendo de [00.ARCHIVO.xlsm], por ejemplo supongamos que los has llamado: Minuevonombre.xlsm, guardar y salir.
Después en el fichero de Producción (también en una copia!) abre el menú de vínculos y da click a "Cambiar Origen" y te pedirá que busques con el explorador el nuevo fichero de vinculo Minuevonombre.xlsm. Después dale a Actualizar datos.
Y mira si te va.

Si no te va, es que igual se ha perdido la coherencia de las fórmulas...comprueba las referencias de alguna.